# What is the shortest way to write this in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
lam1 = 0.0:0.1:4.0  
lam = 1.60*lam1-0.30*lam1^2 for 0<lam1<=1
lam = lam1+0.30 for 1<=lam1<=4
```

I have a bunch of those. What would be the 'matlab way' of writing that kinda stuff, short of simple looping by indexes  and testing the values of lam1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
lam1 = 0:0.1:4; %lam1 now has 41 elements 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 4.0

lam = lam1;  % just to create another array of the same size, could use zeros()

lam = 1.6*lam1-0.30*lam1.^2;
```

`% note, operating on all elements in both arrays, will overwrite wrong entries in lam next; more elegant (perhaps quicker too) would be to only operate on lam(1:11)`

```
lam(12:end) = lam1(12:end)+0.3;
```

but if you've got a bunch of these the Matlab way is to write a function to do them.

Oh, and you have `lam1==1` in both conditions, you ought to fix that.

EDIT: for extra terseness you could write:

```
lam = 1.6*(0:0.1:4)-0.3*(0:0.1:4).^2;
lam(12:end) = (1.1:0.1:4)+0.3;
```

In this version I've left 1 in the first part, second part begins at 1.1

Comment: Ugh, compared to that a loop with an IF testing of elements seems a lot easier to read, IMHO.

Comment: Then I bet, @Idigas, you like my 2nd solution even less !  Generally I prefer the vector operations to loops and ifs in Matlab.

Comment: Actually, for some reason I like the 2nd version a lot ... clean and readable (to me, at least) ... thanks Mark !!

Answer (score 5):

I think the cleanest (i.e. easiest to read and interpret) way to do this in MATLAB would be the following:

```
lam = 0:0.1:4;          %# Initial values
lessThanOne = lam < 1;  %# Logical index of values less than 1
lam(lessThanOne) = lam(lessThanOne).*...
                   (1.6-0.3.*lam(lessThanOne));  %# For values < 1
lam(~lessThanOne) = lam(~lessThanOne)+0.3;       %# For values >= 1
```

The above code creates a vector `lam` and modifies its entries using the [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) `lessThanOne`. This solution has the added benefit of working even if the initial values given to `lam` are, say, in descending order (or even unsorted).

Comment: I agree. Except I'd write 'lessThanOneIdx' or something similar instead of 'index'.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but I still like the above a little more. It's more similar to how I write stuff away from keyboard.

Comment: @MatlabDoug - true. And it should be written that way, I agree. But sometimes I write stuff which I barely understand on paper, and then when writing code I want as little as possible extra lines ... I don't know ... 'tis strange, but that's how my mind works.